# Understanding range vector selectors

Tags: prometheus, grafana, kamon

From reading https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/ a 'Range Vector Selectors' are defined as :

> Range vector literals work like instant vector literals, except that
> they select a range of samples back from the current instant.
> Syntactically, a time duration is appended in square brackets ([]) at
> the end of a vector selector to specify how far back in time values
> should be fetched for each resulting range vector element.
>
> In this example, we select all the values we have recorded within the last 5 minutes for all time series that have the metric name
> http_requests_total and a job label set to prometheus:
> http_requests_total{job="prometheus"}[5m]

I'm failing to understand how these selector's behave. My understanding of the query :

```
sum(rate(data_total[1h]))
```

is return the rate of change of the `data_total` metric using a time during of 1h. Is this correct ? Is each point on the graph the sum(rate( of the previous hour ?

`sum(rate(data_total[1h]))` :

From the above definition shouldn't 1h of data be displayed ? Instead may of hours of data are displayed :
[image]

Changing from 1h to 4h :

`sum(rate(data_total[4h]))` :

renders :

[image]

Why has the shape changed when changing from `[1h]` to `[4h]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `range vector` [selector](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors) is just an ordinary time series selector (which is confusingly named `instant vector` selector) with the added lookbehind window in square brackets.

An ordinary time series selector (aka `instant vector` selector) selects time series matching the given filter. For example, `http_requests_total{path=~"/foo/bar|/baz"}` selects time series with the name `http_requests_total` and the `path` label containing either `/foo/bar` or `/baz` values.

The corresponding `range vector` selector with the one hour lookbehind window looks like the following `http_requests_total{path=~"/foo/bar|baz"}[1h]`.

The `range vector` selector can be used in the following places:

- It can be passed to [/api/v1/query](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries). In this case the API returns all the raw samples for matching time series on the interval `(time-d ... time]`, where `time` is the query arg passed to `/api/v1/query`, while `d` is the specified lookbehind window in square brackets of `range vector` selector. See [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/analyzing-prometheus-data-with-external-tools-5f3e5e147639) for details.
- It can be passed to e.g. [rollup functions](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rollup-functions). These functions perform calculations over raw samples on the given lookbehind window in square brackets. The calculations are performed **independently** per each matching time series and per each requested point on the graph. Prometheus datasource in Grafana sends requests to [/api/v1/query_range](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries). This API accepts `start`, `end` and `step` query args and calculates `N=1+(end-start)/step` points per each matching time series at timestamps `start`, `start+step`, `start+2*step`, ..., `start+(N-1)*step`.

Let's look how `rate(m[d])` is calculated on the `start ... end` time range with the given `step`:

- Prometheus selects all the time series matching `m` on the given time range `(start-d .. end]`. Note that the time range starts from `start-d` instead of `start`, where `d` is the provided lookbehind window in square brackets.
- Then Prometheus calculates the average per-second increase rate over the given lookbehind window `d` **individually** per each matching time series per each requested point on the graph.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68223824/prometheus-instant-vector-vs-range-vector/72046294#72046294).